# SUM formula vba code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How is it possible to sum two columns in an excel file into another column. I want to sum Column A with Column B and the result should be shown in column C, but how can I do it in vba?

For example:

Col A.

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3

Col B.

1. 1
2. 2
3. List item

Col C.

1. 2
2. 4
3. 6

Answer (score 2):

if that's all you need, why not just use the excel formula for cell C1 
"=SUM(A1,B1)"? if it's part of a more complex vba macro you can use

```
cells(1,3).Formula = "=SUM(A1,B1)"
Range("C1:C3").FillDown
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using vba because we should not use it in the excel sheet directlly. How can I check "if A is blank then C is blank?

Comment: first, if this is a homework or class work, i encourage you to use the vba resource that come with the vba, just press F1 and it will pop up so you can search for what you are looking for, in this case "sum" and "if" condition.
otherwise, are you supposed to not use it in excel? or are you not allowed to use excel formulas at all? if so, i would suggest Gary's Student solution as mine will leave a formula in the excel sheet.

Comment: Yes it is a student assignment, but i must use the vba and not the excel formulas.

Comment: well then, try using the help built in, anywhere on the vba IDE press F1 and use that to look up the IF function, try to understand and use it, if you don't manage to use it, post here your try and what error or fualty output you get, and we'll help you get it right, but the most importent thing is trying first by youself otherwise as you progress in the course you will not have a good basis of understanding.

Comment: Ok I tried =IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1);(ISBLANK(B1)));""; In the formula and it worked. But when I try it in the VBA code it is not working. "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),(ISBLANK(B1))),"",((A1)-B1)"

Comment: that's becuase quatation marks are speciel charcters in VBA they mean start and end of strings, you need to escape them when inserting them inside a string, the escape charcter is funny enough another quatation mark, so every time you want to imply a blank "" you need to insert double quatations """" (that's four instead of two).
`"=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),(ISBLANK(B1))),"""",((A1)-B1)"`

Answer (score 0):

There many ways.  For example:

```
Sub AddColumns()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

You could also use *Evaluate()* which is slightly faster and slightly more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

You're not posing the problem very well ... if you're interested in adding values in a column (like you) wrote, I don't see any reason why you would want to use VBA at all. Just add the values in the cells directly.

Apart from that, you can always use a function like

```
Function DoColumnStuff( column_1 as Range, column_2 as Range ) as Variant

  Dim returnColumn() as Variant

  ' resize returnColumn to a sensible size and
  ' populate it with sensible values, derived out of
  ' column_1 and column_2

  DoColumnStuff = returnColumn
End Function
```

So, you could do with your arguments whatever your heart desires and return that as a column. Two things to note: Firstly, if you want the function to return a *column*, you will have to resize `returnColumn` to a 2-dimensional array with 1 column dimension (e.g. 10 rows, 1 column ~~> use `Redim returnColumn( 1 to 10, 1 to 1 )` for resizing). Secondly, you need to insert the function as a Matrix-Function in Excel, i.e. select the whole output range, type in the formula and press Shift-Enter

Answer (score 0):

As Gary's Student said, there are many ways, one is below
if

A1 contains 1 and B1 contains 1
A2 contains 2 and B2 contains 2
A3 contains 3 and B3 contains 3

in C1 Column paste the below formula

```
 =IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"Either A or B is Blank",SUM(A1:B1))
```

and select the column C1 to C3 and press Ctrl + D

in VBA,

```
Sub Sample()
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 1) = "" And Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
Cells(i, 3) = "Both are Blank"
ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
Cells(i, 3) = "B is Blank"
ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "" And Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
Cells(i, 3) = "A is Blank"
ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i, 2)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

or you can use Function. Directly into excel sheet like formula Simply type sumformula(A1,B1) in C1, results will appears in C1 row after enter.

please see below

```
Function sumformula(a As String, b As String)
If a = "" And b = "" Then
    sumformula = "Both are Blank"
ElseIf a <> "" And b = "" Then
    sumformula = "B is Blank"
ElseIf a = "" And b <> "" Then
    sumformula = "A is Blank"
ElseIf a <> "" And b <> "" And IsNumeric(a) = False And IsNumeric(b) = True Then
    sumformula = "Column A is not a number"
ElseIf a <> "" And b <> "" And IsNumeric(a) = True And IsNumeric(b) = False Then
    sumformula = "Column B is not a number"
ElseIf a <> "" And b <> "" And IsNumeric(a) = True And IsNumeric(b) = True Then
    sumformula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(a, b)
End If
End Function
```

Hope it helps